# how to Mitigate UDP flood with PIX

Tags: cisco-pix

G'day,

can any one tell me how to Mitigate UDP flood with PIX

cheers

Answer (score 0):

If this is a live flood, you can block attacking host with the [shun](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/command/reference/s8.html#wp1423457) command
For general flood protection, take a look to [threat-detection](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/command/reference/t.html#wp1482339) commands if you are running a recent PIX OS version. 
With more details we could help you better (OS version, kind of UDP flood, etc..)